# Azure Data factory: PostgreSQL to blob storage if PostgreSQL is in a private subnet (Azure)

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

So I want to create a copy activity in Azure Data factory. From PostgreSQL to Azure blob storage.
As **my vm (postgreSQL)** is in a private subnet in Azure.
So my question is, is it possible to create a pipeline from a vm which is in a **private subnet**?

[image]

**updates**

So currently this is the situation.
I have created a private endpoint **postgresql-2-data-storage** and now I want to connect datafactory to my vm which is in a Azure vNet with a private ip address **172.16.101.4**

[image]

when I click on create new Linked service, I don't see Azure resource(vNet) or private endpoint.

Comment: you want to create pipeline inside VM using private subnet or outside VM private subnet? from diagram it looks like it is outside of VM

Comment: @PratikLad as the data is in the postgreSQL and postgreSQL is in a VM. So I don't know how I can tell you wether it is inside or outside. 
But my main purpose it to pull data from a table which is inside the postgreSQL and of course postgreSQL is on a Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

> PostgreSQL to blob storage if PostgreSQL is in a private subnet

AFAIK, to Assess the database from On-premises or from Azure private network you need to configure a [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to connect to it.

Using Azure Private Link, you can connect to various platform as a service (PaaS) deployment in Azure via a private endpoint and to access data from Private network, you need to Create private endpoint on Azure data factory an add that endpoint to same virtual network where your VM is present.

Go to your ADF settings >> Networking >> Private endpoint connection >> Private endpoint.

[image]

Then fill all details an configure it. after this install SHIR in your VM and connect your PostgreSQL to Data factory

Follow this document [To Install Self-Hosted Integration Runtime on Azure VM by using Private EndPoint](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2022/01/how-to-install-self-hosted-integration.html) for more information.

Comment: ah so you have explained if I have to pull the data from a vm which is on premise. Sorry my bad. That vm is also in the azure.

Comment: you can access data from VM's which are on azure also.

Comment: when I click on Create new linked service in azure data factory, I don't see any option to connect to my vm, which is in azure vNet. I have already created a private endpoint and it is connected with my vNet